# NodeMCU not detected by computer

Tags: nodemcu

I have bought today a NodeMCU v2 (I think).

I connected my NodeMCU to my laptop with a microUSB to USB cable, the same one that I use to transfer photos from my phone to my laptop. The laptop simply does not show me the NodeMCU while connected (I am running Windows 8 for reference). It makes the little sound when I plug it in (also a small blue light flashes once) or out and the Wi-Fi AI-THINKER_2CD750 appears in the Wi-Fi tab.

It doesn't try to install the drivers or anything, nothing happens. I tried to install the drivers myself from the github page, that did not work either, it says that they are preinstalled.

Comment: The first thing really is to figure out which module exactly you're using (see https://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/). Based on the built-in USB-to-TTL chip on that module we might then be able to point you to the correct driver.

Comment: It is a second generation 1.0 board(the v2 one as i saw that there was a very similar v3 one). Thank you for your concern.

Comment: If it's a [V2](http://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/JaYRrVJ) then it's likely got a [CP2101 USB-to-TTL chip](https://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/#official-vs-unofficial). Drivers for those are available from the manufacturer at http://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but I assume that it's the same drivers for CP2102, as that is what it says on the back of the PCB.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say CP2102

Comment: Tried it, downloaded and installed the drivers, still nothing(as in it didn't do anything at all, absolutely nothing changed). At the end of the driver installation it says something along the lines of "No device detected for updates", which again i think is because of the wire maybe? or my NodeMCU model is faulty?

Comment: Switched to another laptop. Windows 10 this time. Plugged it in, the driver installation thing appeared but I had to go to do something so did not get to see whether it completed or something else. The node still is undetected by this laptop as well. Downloaded the drivers on this one as well and installed them. It said "Device updated" this time. Still no COM with the node, thinking of giving it back if I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I faced a similar error where my NodeMCU was being detected as a faulty CP2101 device.
I tried to install the NodeMCU drivers but it didn't work.
Then I landed up using this link: https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers to install the CP210x Universal Windows Driver.
This was installed correctly and I was able to use the NodeMCU again.

I would also recommend taking a look at your board. Not all the ESP8266 development boards use the same peripherals. So you'll have to find a driver accordingly.

Comment: For me just swapping the microusb cable 3 times worked

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me too. For me The board was bad. After replacing with new one it was working with same drivers

Answer (score 2):

I had to install the driver for the NodeMCU manually: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit/tree/master/Drivers. Afterwards, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Mac (Big Sur) and Windows 10.  Tried everything. Saw this about the USB ports, still no love.  Then I swapped out the cable for giggles and it worked. So much time wasted. I used the cable in the past and it worked, also it powered on the device so I was lured into a false sense of security.  Anyway, swapping out the cable did the trick.  Test a second cable even if you think you are sure the cable is not the problem!

Comment: +1. Changing the cable did the trick. There are microUSB charging cables and microUSB data cables. Please make sure you're using a data cable.

Answer (score 1):

For future people with this issue try using a USB 2.0 port. I had mine plugged into a 3.0 and it wouldn't detect.

My troubleshooting (with NodeMCU 12-E, V3):

I tried plugging it after removing the driver from the Device Manager in Windows 10, reinstalling the (CH341SER) driver and 3 cable swaps. In the end my laziness foced me to use my 2.0 front panel. The 3.0 everywhere else wouldn't work.